# Что такое "цугундер"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Доведет он тебя до цугундера" — говорят, когда хотят предупредить, что затея добром не кончится. А что такое, собственно, "цугундер"? Явно слово немецкое.

Answer (score 6):

По мнению Преображенского, слово имеет "белорусское" происхождение, то есть из тех краев, где в ходу были немецко-еврейские разговорные словообразования. Zug - упряжка, тяга, волочение и т.п.; under - "под". Таким образом, слово **цугундер** означает - "на привязи", "под строгим доглядом, в кандалах"... "Взять на цугундер" -  заключить под охрану, в каталажку, посадить в яму, на цепь.

Comment: А почему не Zu Hunder т.е. к собакам.

Answer (score 2):

В сельской белорусской школе в глубинке, в середине ХХ века, выражение "взять кого-то на цыгундры" употребляли в смысле принудительной помощи в учебе отстающему ученику, который самостоятельно не справлялся с учебными заданиями. Как мне объясняли, "брали на буксир", не давали отстать.